# What is the best way to communicate binary data in TCP sockets

Tags: tcp, c#-3.0

I am developing a client/server application in c#.net. Now I am going to pick the communication mechanism use in client/server packets. I want to know, what will be the best format for sending and receiving data on sockets.

Xml serialize or
Binary serialize(i am using Marshalling, demonstrated at i.e. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ca6d5z7.aspx )

Although Xml serialize will do the work, but as we know, it will be slower. So I think binary marshalling will be the good option. But in this technique, I have to create lot of structs for my each individual packet used in communication. I need help, please suggest if its the only best way to use in this scenerio or there exists some better way to acheive the goal.

Comment: Xml being slowish costs a dime an hour.  You cost a hundred bucks an hour.  Tough to break even.  Use WCF or Google's Protocol Buffers.

Comment: It all depends on the number of messages/sec you need to exchange between your server and the clients. If that traffic is never expected to reach very high levels then I agree with @HansPassant

Answer (score 0):

Unless the Xml serialize can fit in one frame, (1480 bytes), then binary marshalling will send fewer IP packets.  Yes you will have to define structs for your packet.

I recommend that you define a struct for a common packet header for all your packet types, which include the number of bytes in the packet.  If you have different packet types, you might also include the packet type in the common header.